# Cómo crear una base de datos local en SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Necesito crear un fichero de base de datos **SQL Server** con extensión `.sdf` o `.mdf`, pero esto tiene que ser generado a puro **código C#**. Pudiera alguién ayudarme?

En SQLite se hace muy sencillo:

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(@"D:\dato.db");
```

Comment: Gracias por la edición **Luiggi Mendoza**

Comment: Buscaste? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015142/creating-a-database-programmatically-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Ojo que SQL Server no funciona igual que SQLite.

SQLite está diseñado para que pueda correr correctamente con tan solo un archivo `.db` válido.

En el caso de SQL Server, no porque tengas un archivo `.mdf` válido significa que puedas correr la base de datos así no más. En el caso de SQL Server, requiere además que tengas una instalación completa de SQL Server en tu máquina. Solo el archivo `.mdf` no es suficiente. No es como SQLite, donde todo revuelve alrededor del archivo nada más. Son 2 arquitecturas completamente diferentes.

Pero asumiendo que tienes claro la diferencia y que ya tienes un SQL Server instalado correctamente en tu máquina, y que tengas forma de conectarte a ella con los permisos necesarios para poder crear bases de datos, entonces el código para lograrlo es simplemente:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection("<aquí le pones tu cadena de conexión>"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("create database nueva_base_de_datos", conn))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola **sstan**, siempre muy servicial. Esa explicación que me diste la tengo clara. Voy a tener agregar la base de datos `.sdf` con los componentes de **Visual Studio** y luego darle uso. Gracias

Comment: Si bien no es lo mismo que SQL Lite, la versión CE de SQL Server puede funcionar sin tener SQL Server instalado. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709. Aunque creo que no es lo que el OP buscaba.

Answer (score 0):

En SQL Server se encesitan al menos 2 archivos, un `.mdf`para el archivo primario de la Base de Datos y uno `.ldf` para los logs. En caso de Necesitar uno (o varios) Archivos Secundarios los creas con la extensión `.ndf`.

La sintaxis en T-SQL para generar una Base de Datos es la siguiente:

```
CREATE DATABASE Archive   
ON  
PRIMARY    
    (NAME = Arch1,  
    FILENAME = 'D:\SalesData\archdat1.mdf',  
    SIZE = 100MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 200,  
    FILEGROWTH = 20),  
    ( NAME = Arch2,  
    FILENAME = 'D:\SalesData\archdat2.ndf',  
    SIZE = 100MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 200,  
    FILEGROWTH = 20),  
    ( NAME = Arch3,  
    FILENAME = 'D:\SalesData\archdat3.ndf',  
    SIZE = 100MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 200,  
    FILEGROWTH = 20)  
LOG ON   
   (NAME = Archlog1,  
    FILENAME = 'D:\SalesData\archlog1.ldf',  
    SIZE = 100MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 200,  
    FILEGROWTH = 20),  
   (NAME = Archlog2,  
    FILENAME = 'D:\SalesData\archlog2.ldf',  
    SIZE = 100MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 200,  
    FILEGROWTH = 20) ;  
GO
```

Puedes obtener más información en https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-cl/library/ms176061.aspx